# Function output empty values in wordpress functions.php but works when called from another page

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function get_people_cats($taxonomy) {

    $output = ''; 
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
    $count = count($terms);
    if ( $count > 0 ):
        foreach ( $terms as $term ):
            $output .= "'". $term->name ."'". '=>';
            $output .= "'". $term->term_id."',";
        endforeach;
    endif;
    return $output; 
}
```

This function returns a list of custom taxonomies and which words are found if the function is called in a template. But I want to assign the the function values to a variable in `functions.php`, and it's returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works fine in my functions.php file on a local site:

```
function get_people_cats( $taxonomy ) {

    $output = ''; 
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
    $count = count( $terms );
    if ( $count > 0 ):
        foreach ( $terms as $term ):
            $output .= $term->name.'=>'.$term->term_id;
        endforeach;
    endif;
    return $output; 
}

echo get_people_cats('category');
```

Comment: thanks it works for standard categories but when I enter a custom taxonomy as the function argument its returns this: `array(""=>"",""=>"")`

Comment: does it not need the speech makers surrounding the key and values?

Comment: Posted a follow up answer below so that the code would be formatted

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting terms back it's probably due to where the taxonomy is being registered. If it's being registered in an init hook then you're likely trying to print them out before the taxonomy has actually been registered.

You can test it with the following:

```
function get_people_cats( $taxonomy ) {
    $output = ''; 
    $terms = get_terms('category');
    $count = count( $terms );
    if ( $count > 0 ):
        foreach ( $terms as $term ):
            $output .= $term->name.'=>'.$term->term_id;
        endforeach;
    endif;
    return $output; 
}

function echo_cats() { 
    echo get_people_cats('taxonomy_name', array('hide_empty' => 0) );
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'echo_cats');
```

By hooking into wp_footer it's not being called until well after any plugins that might have registered the taxonomy.

// UPDATE //

Got it. To create an array just do this:

```
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false) );
if( !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
         $types[$term->term_id] = $term->name;
    }
} 
return $types;   
}
```

That will give you an array of `$term->id => $term->name --` you may want to reverse that depending on how you're using the array.

Comment: hmm... I copied the code, added the parameter and it does not output anything at all.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: You swapped out taxonomy_name for the name of your custom taxonomy in get_people_cats() ?  I tested it locally using a custom taxonomy (speciality) and it works no problem. Keep in mind it will print at the very bottom of your page -- oh, and you have to have wp_footer() in your template.

Comment: yes I can see it at the bottom but it seems as though I cannot get it in into a variable to pass as value in the code below.
`array(

  'type'    => 'dropdown',
  'holder'   => 'div',
  'class'   => '',
  'heading'   => __('Insert Cetegory ID'),
  'param_name'  => 'category_id', // Must be the same as actual shortcode parameter name  
  'value'   => $myArrayHere,
  'description'  => __('Enter the category ID'),
 )`

Comment: Updated the answer above.

Comment: seems like what I'm looking for but I get a blank page and when I comment out the code it starts working again. I changed $taxonomy to 'person_category' and put the $terms as the value for of the array

Comment: its missing and an open curly brace

Comment: I tried pretty much everything I can think of without success.

Comment: I created a shortcode and I am crating an interface to it using wp-bakery visual composer.

one of their field types is a dropdown that accepts an array as a value, and I want a pull a list of customer post-type category to choose from when adding that component to the page.

http://kb.wpbakery.com/index.php?title=Mapping_Params
I see examples in their plugin code and its the same as we have but when I copy, it just returns nothing when modified.

Answer (score 0):

If your Taxonomies are actually creaetd with a plugin instead of creating them with code in your functions.php the result of get_terms will be empty untill the taxonomies have initiated, which is on plugin level initiation better yet, most probably using the 'init' hook, so you would have to hook your function after the hook and use it only in your theme template files (not in functions.php) basicly you do something like:

```
add_action('init', 'get_people_cats', 9999);
```

Then you would call it normaly: `$cats = get_people_cats('person_category');`

Hope this solves your issue (I know it took me around an hour to solve this when I ran into it).